# Flutter Web giving xml error when calling apis

Tags: flutter, cors

I host my flutter app on firebase hosting. When I'm calling apis it's giving me xml http erorr cors error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://kapi.kakao.com/v1/payment/ready' from origin

'http://localhost:52700' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. ]
```

I tried solution with local while blocking cors but i want solution when flutter web app is hosted.